# Custom fields in Razorpay Checkout form

Tags: javascript, razorpay

I am using `razorpay` for online payments in India,

I want a custom fields like billing address should be store at razorpay account with checkout form. I know about `notes` which stores a custom data to razorpay account, but i am not getting any link for setting these fields in checkout form.

my code :

```
var options = {
                "key": [key]
                "amount": [amount],
                "name": [name],
                "description": [desc],
                "image": "logo.png",
                "handler": function (response) {
                    // handler
                },
                "prefill": {
                    "name": userName,
                    "email": userEmail
                },
                "notes": {
                    "billing_name": "Stripe",
                    "billing_address_country": "United States",
                    "billing_address_zip": "94111",
                    "billing_address_state": "CA",
                    "billing_address_line1": "1234 Main Street",
                    "billing_address_city": "San Francisco",
                    "billing_address_country_code": "US",
                },
                "theme": {
                    "color": "#008DD2"
                },
                "modal": {
                    "ondismiss": function () {
                        // code
                    }
                }
            };
            var rzp = new Razorpay(options);
            rzp.open();
```

So, my question is that how can i get all `notes` fields in razorpay checkout form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Notes* is a generic field where you can add any custom required details.

**Here is what their documentation says:**

> Any additional fields you want to associate with the payment. Usually
>   includes things like shipping address. Upto 15 notes fields may be
>   specified in this way.

You code here will work

```
"notes": {
                    "billing_name": "Stripe",
                    "billing_address_country": "United States",
                    "billing_address_zip": "94111",
                    "billing_address_state": "CA",
                    "billing_address_line1": "1234 Main Street",
                    "billing_address_city": "San Francisco",
                    "billing_address_country_code": "US",
                }
```

These details will be available in customer details API, and will not be shown in Razorpay Dashboard.